# Convert MVC2 .NET 4 application to run on .NET 3.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, downgrade

This might seem like an odd request, but is there any simple way to downgrade my ASP.NET MVC2 application running on .NET 4 (developed in VS2010) to run on .NET 3.5? I'm asking because the server I will be using to host the application on is within my university and only has.NET 3.5 installed.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP.NET MVC 2 is built against .Net 3.5 so there is no downgrade needed there. The only problem you might have is your own code - if you are using some .Net 4.0 specific stuff you will have to change it. For starters change your projects target framework (in project properties) to 3.5 and check if it still builds.